# removing the xml tags in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rexml

I am reading data from an xml doc and placing it on a web page using rails and REMXL.  I use

```
@description1=XPath.match( xmldoc, "////description" )
```

to get the info into an array and just loop through in my view. However when using

```
<%= h(@description1[k]) %>
```

so it looks like

```
<description>fuzzy slippers</description>
```

on the web page. Is there a good way of removing the tags?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath you are using will return a set of nodes. To get only the content, use:

```
@description1 = XPath.match(xmldoc, "////description/text()")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into httparty: http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
<%= h(@description1[k].text) %>
```

What does it show?